# Javascript and Php (MVC)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i'm creating my own MVC Framework.
I have a basic form in my view

```
<form action="?" method="post" >
    <input type="hidden" name="envoie" value="envoie" />
    <?php dico('INSCRIPTION_NOM'); ?><input id="name" type="text" name="name" /><br />
    <?php dico('INSCRIPTION_EMAIL'); ?><input id="email" type="text" name="email" /><br />
    <?php dico('INSCRIPTION_PWD'); ?><input id="pwd" type="password" name="pwd" /><br />
    <input type="button" value="<?php dico('INSCRIPTION_SINSCRIRE'); ?>" onclick="verifForm(document.getElementById('email').value);"/>
</form>
```

when I clock on the button they have a javascript function like that :

```
function verifForm(email) {
    var url ="?c=Inscription&a=VerifForm&email="+email;
    $.get(url, function(data){
        alert('resultat == '+data);
    });
}
```

Inscription was my controllers and VerifForm an method of the controller. email was the value of a input.

The Php function was :

```
public function actionVerifForm() {
        echo "OK";
}
```

When i click on the button i have all the code of the page on my alert but i only want the message "OK".

Thanks for helping me

Comment: what do you mean by *i have all the code of the page on my alert*? you mean your PHP code is alerted?

Comment: You can test my appl on http://iftp.axioweb.fr/?c=Inscription&a=Formulaire for seeing the problem of the alert message

Answer (score 1):

what you are doing is AJAX, am i right? the `data` parameter IS your result. AJAX returns the `echo`-ed page as a string. if you mean to place it in the page, try jQuery [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) for a text only, escaped version.

```
function verifForm(email) {
    var url ="?c=Inscription&a=VerifForm&email="+email;
    $.get(url, function(data){
        $('#container-id-here').html(data); //html insert
        $('#container-id-here').text(data); //text insert
    });
}
```

and in your PHP, since you are doing AJAX, you should only echo what you need returned, and not the whole HTML mark-up (which means no `<html><head>...</head></html>`

Comment: i'm gonna test the .html and .text but i need my data in an alert.

Comment: Work if i want my data on div but i need the data on my alert

Comment: it's working properly actually. the problem is that your PHP is not just echoing the result, but is including the HTML mark-up as well! the php should only echo what you want in order to return what you need.

Comment: if you are creating an MVC and this is your default view, you should also create an additional "ajax-only" view, with no additional HTML mark-up.

Comment: it's not my default view it's a registration view. What i need un my ajax-only view?

Comment: yes, a view that returns only what you need, one that does not include the full mark-up. The HTML and JS are fine. this, you should change in your PHP file. the php should echo only the "OK" and not the whole HTML.

Comment: Ok i see what u wanna say. but where i have to put my html mark up? Because if i have a lot of views i have to put all the html markup in all the view

Comment: No, don't put all the HTML markup in every view. Only where you need it. You definitely don't need it in an ajax call. I would actually recommend starting with a non-ajax approach, and regular form submissions to understand things better.

Comment: for example how can i insert a menu ?

Comment: you only wanted "OK" returned. but your PHP is echoing *everything* including the "OK". you should remove everything else but the "OK". since it's your custom MVC Framework, you should find out which part echoes the `<html>`, the `<head>`, the `<body>` and *omit* them. your i think you got it since i only see `resultat==email` already

Comment: that's why you should create a default view (that returns standard HTML pages, which has menus and all) and ajax view (which only returns what's needed). you must pass a parameter to your PHP indicating what "face" of that view to use: HTML, AJAX etc.

Comment: it's gonna be hard to separate HTML and AJAX view for me i prefere have a sample page and juste insert my other between <body></body>